# Error while deploying a Python Function app to Azure

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I've got a simple timer trigger function app which works locally using VS Code. When deploying to Azure from within VS Code, I get a failure. Few lines of the message are as follows.

12:33:30 icl777: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0) 12:33:30 icl777: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version` GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:33:30 icl777: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)

I have installed Python 3.9.12 (64-bit) and Azure Functions Core Tools - 3.0.3904 (x64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to deploy the Python Azure Function (Timer Trigger) to the Azure using VS Code, the deployment is failed.

[image]

As Per this recent issue in Python SDKs mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71783107/16630138), rolled back to Python version 3.8 and tried to deploy in Azure using VS Code.

It deployed to Azure successfully to the 3.8 version Python Azure Function App:

[image]

For a Temporary workaround, try rolling back the python version to 3.8 and also follow the update on Python SDK 3.9 updates on the above-mentioned thread solution containing GitHub Repos of the Tracking Changes of Python SDK 3.9 related to Azure.