# VS Code Azure deployment of Python Http Trigger function fails - GLIB_2.27 not found

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my locally fine running function to Azure

- VS Code Version: 1.65.2
- Azure Tools v0.2.1
- Azure Functions v1.6.1

My `requirements.txt`

```
msrest
msrestazure
azure-core
azure-common
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-storage-blob
azure-keyvault-secrets
```

The deploy starts getting problematic from here:

```
12:41:40 ShopifyWebhookHandler:   python: 3.9.12
12:41:40 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
12:41:40 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: version `GLIBC_2.30' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.26' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/lib/libpython3.9.so.1.0)
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.9.12/bin/python3.9
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Running pip install...
12:41:41 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Done in 0 sec(s).
12:41:43 ShopifyWebhookHandler: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.9 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
12:41:43 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Deployment Failed.
12:41:51 ShopifyWebhookHandler: Deployment failed.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Created also an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/3101) on Github

Zin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is linked to and open Github issue with Microsoft Oryx.

> Hey folks, apologies for the breaking changes that this issue has caused for your applications.

> Oryx has pre-installed Python SDKs on the build images; if the SDK
> that your application is targeting is not a part of this set, Oryx
> will fallback to dynamic installation, which attempts to pull a Python
> SDK that meets your application's requirements from our storage
> account, where we backup a variety of Python SDKs.

> In this case, it appears that the Python 3.9.12 SDK was published to
> our storage account yesterday around 3:10 PM PST (10:10 PM UTC), and
> applications targeting Python 3.9 are now pulling down this 3.9.12 SDK
> rather than the previously published 3.9.7 SDK.

> I'm optimistic that we should have this resolved in the next couple of
> hours, but in the meantime, as folks have mentioned above, if you are
> able to downgrade your application to using Python 3.8, please
> consider doing so. Alternatively, if your build/deployment method
> allows you to snap to a specific patch version of Python, please
> consider targeting Python 3.9.7, which was the previous 3.9.* version
> that can be pulled down during dynamic installation.

> Again, apologies for the issues that this has caused you all.

[Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1330#issuecomment-1091739027)

Temporarily try rolling your Python version back down to Python 3.8.

[Azure function cli docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi%2Cazurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#changing-python-version)